# Deleting two lines from a .txt file when the corresponding link is clicked

Tags: php

I am trying to create a way for accounts to be removed from "user_accounts.txt" which stores the usernames and passwords on separate lines.

I am trying to make a list of the undeleted accounts to replace the .txt file... so effectively the account will be deleted when the link is clicked.

I have managed to get the usernames to display as a links. However, when I click on a link it does not delete it, it diverts me to a page with error 404.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Before anyone mentions security issues with storing account details in a .txt file, I am fully aware of this. I am still learning PHP and I am focusing on learning and understanding basics first. I will focus on security at a later date, once I have it working. My website is used for educational purposes only.

All help is greatly appreciated.

My code is:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
$delete = htmlspecialchars($_GET["account"]);

$newAccountList = "";

$file = fopen("user_accounts.txt", "r") or exit ("Unable to open file");

while(!feof($file))
{
$accountUsername = trim(str_replace("\n", "", fgets($file)));
$accountPassword = trim(str_replace("\n", "", fgets($file)));

if($delete != $accountUsername)
{
if($newAccountList == "")
{
$newAccountList = $accountUsername;
}
else
{
$newAccountList = $newAccountList."\n".$accountUsername;
}

$newAccountList = $newAccountList."\n".$accountPassword;
}
}
$file = fopen("user_accounts.txt", "w") or exit ("Unable to open file");

fwrite($file, $newAccountList);

fclose($file);
}
?>

<?php

$file = fopen("user_accounts.txt", "r") or exit ("Unable to open file");    
while(!feof($file))
{
$username = fgets($file);
$password = fgets($file);

echo "<a href='user_accounts.php?account=".$username."'>".$username."</a><br><br>";
}

fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: Why not use a database? also storing password as plain-text is very bad specially if your file is within your root directory and not protected.

Comment: This is a college assignment. My tutor has asked for it to be in a .txt file. I'm still learning the basics. As I mentioned in my original post, I am aware of security issues.

Comment: Learning MySQL with PHP is way easier than with a text file ;) but if you cannot use a database for your assignment I will understand that but still you should at least encrypt your passwords.

Comment: If you're getting a 404, then it means it's not finding your php at all. This suggests the problem is with your link. Does the page with the 404 error show the same URL (in your browser) as your first page with the list of usernames?

Comment: Also, walk before you can run...don't worry about encrypting stuff yet. You're aware that this isn't the right way to do it properly, which is enough at this stage. =)

Comment: @Chris being aware does not mean they will learn/fix it later. If you do a simple check over this site you will see that over **60%** of the people learning it never bother to learn it and never care to it right they just want the answer that fix their issue.

Comment: @Chris Its taking me to a different page of a hosting website with /error_404? on the end.

Comment: When I try to go back to the page I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/my_user_id/public_html/remove_user.php on line 92
</html> which is the line after the end of my code?

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem may be because of the link you're using because you may forgot to put the correct name of you're script.
2. I don't think there's any mistake in you're code but you may have some problems when it comes to runing the script without a GET variable so replace the following line :

> ```
>    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
>        {
>         ...
>         }
> ```

With :

```
if(isset($_GET['account'])){
...
}
```

Comment: I have changed my link and used if(isset($_GET['account'])){ and still I am getting the /error_404? thing.

Answer (score 0):

After staring at this code for hours, I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. I was echoing the wrong page! Should have been the 'remove_user.php' instead of 'user_accounts.php' (this page is a .txt file, not .php anyway!).

Thank you for all that had some input :)